# Can I use gyroscope sensor in two application at same time in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to use the gyroscope sensor in Android simultaneously in two different applications. I know that it's not required to bind the sensor in an application so I am assuming that we can use the gyroscope sensor in two different applications at the same time.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use anything in two applications at the same time because Android OS prevents applications to work after an app loses its focus. But you can do it with 2 `services` and you can fetch data from the application when needed.

For example:

```
//App1
    //Service1
        //read gyro data, write it to application space(db or sharedpreferences)

    //App1 Activity
        //read data from application space and show it to the user

//App2
    //Service2
        //read gyro data, write it to application space(db or sharedpreferences)
    //App2 Activity
        //read data from application space and show it to the user
```

So you can have continuous data flow at the same time for each app.